# ASP.NET MVC Ignore route containing a dot

Tags: c#, asp.net

Is there any way how to ignore all routes containing a DOT? Something like `routes.IgnoreRoute(@"\.")`

**Background of the issue:**

I have a React js frontend app which has defined route
`<Route path="patients/new" component={PatientRegistration}/>`
However if I enter `localhost:port/patients/new` I got the error

> http://localhost:5425/patients/built/bundle.js 404 (Not Found)

I am not sure why is this happening but the workaround with the ignoring the dot should work.

**ASP.NET MVC current RegisterRoutes.cs**:

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
    routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

    routes.MapPageRoute("Default", "{*anything}", "~/index.html");
}
```

Comment: `localhost:port/patients/new` does not contain a dot.

Comment: yes but the error is saying that `patients/built/bundle.js` not found. Again, I do not know why is this happening.

Comment: Do you have `<modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" />` in your Web.config file?

Comment: error `bundle.js:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <` when accessing localhost:port/patients/new